# Determine at which scrollTop values an element will appear and disappear on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an element that has a complex position on a page, meaning that it could have been transformed with css, it could be in a parent that has a sticky position etc...
Now, how can I compute at what value of `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop` my element will first appear, and at what value it will disappear ?

If you run this code, when the element first enters the screen you will see in the console at which scroll position it did so, and then when it exited. I need to know those two values at any point in time, no matter how much scroll has already been applied, if the window has been resized etc...

```js
let entry = false;
let exit = false;
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  let y = element.getBoundingClientRect().y
  if (!entry && y < window.innerHeight && y + element.clientHeight >= 0) {
    entry = true
    console.log("element enters the screen at", window.scrollY);
  }
  if (entry && !exit && y + element.clientHeight < 0) {
    exit = true;
    console.log("element exits the screen at", window.scrollY);
  }
})

setInterval(()=>{
  document.scrollingElement.scrollTop++
},5)
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

#parent {
  height: 500vh;
}

#space {
  height: calc(100vh + 19px);
}

#sticky {
  height: 275vh;
  top: 0px;
  position: sticky;
}

#element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 40px;
  transform: translate(100px, -30px)
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="space"></div>
  <div id="sticky">
    <div id="element"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using `element.getBoundingClientRect().y`, I have computed the initial distance from the top of the document to the top of the element by summing all of its parents' "offsetTop" values . But for example when the element is contained in a parent that has a sticky position, and this parent is in the "fixed" state, scrolling will totally change this total offset value and mess everything up.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to get the scroll Y property from the window, instead of the element. Also, to detect if the user has scrolled I would implement a `onscroll` event listener.

Check the code below:

```
//elem represents the element that you want to hide

let elem = document.querySelector(...)

//the onscroll event will execute when the user scrolls
 window.onscroll = () => {

 //200 is a example value, but you can put any scrollY position by testing when do 
 //you want to hide the element

 if(window.scrollY === 200) {

  //this is a example of how I would hide the element via CSS but you can 
  //use another method just as changing the opacity.
  elem.style.display = "none"

 }

}
```

If you want to know more about the onscroll event you can go to the [documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp).
If you want to know more about the scrollY property you can go to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY).

Also, if you don´t want to hide the element by using `display:none;` you can use `opacity:0;` or `visibility:hidden;`. Check the differences [here](https://thisthat.dev/display-none-vs-opacity-0-vs-visibility-hidden/).

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, I edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the scrollTop value?

**1. If you want to do something to the element when it has been scrolled off-screen or appears in-screen**

Then you don't have to calculate this value yourself. You can use the IntersectionObserver API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

```js
new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries, observer) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      const isOutside = (entry.intersectionRatio === 0);
      if (isOutside) {
        // Do something when it has scrolled off-screen
      } else {
        // Do something when it has scrolled in-screen
      }
    }
  },
  {
    threshold: 0.0001 // Because sometimes a pixel in not visible on screen but the intersectionRatio is already 0
  }
);
```

**2. Or if you want to do something to the element when it is a certain amount of pixels away from the screen boundaries**

You might want to use the optional rootMargin option of the IntersectionObserver:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/rootMargin

```js
rootMargin: `1000px 50px 20px 80px`
```

**3. Or if you want to do something to the element when it is fully visible in-screen**

You can increase the optional threshold option of the IntersectionObserver to 1:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver/thresholds

```js
threshold: 1
```

**4. But if you still want to calculate the scrollTop yourself**

You must add the current scrollTop value of the scrolling element to the element.getBoundingClientRect().y value.

```
const y = scrollingElement.scrollTop + element.getBoundingClientRect().y;
```

Comment: I do need to calculate the scrollTop myself, but what you propose doesn't work in all situations.